# how to overcome the must be derived from your Site URL when locally developing

Tags: facebook, debugging, localhost

Or how to develop locally and then upload to the server .
how can i develop Facebook app that in the end will be on my server .
but for now i need to develop it locally.   for debugging and testing 
and Facebook doesn't give me the option to set Website,Canvas URL and Secure Canvas URL as localhost .
for example:

```
http://localhost:8090/myapp
```

what is the right way to debug and develop in php or java facebook app

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a domain name so Facebook can always reach you.
You also better buy a cheap webhosting plan because you want your app to be 24/7.
You can use FTP to manage the files that are on your website. (google for FileZilla)
Make sure that you buy webhosting with PHP.
Just Google for "cheap webhosting php" and you will get tons of results.